# Spring boot MongoDB Change Streams doesn't work

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive

I try to subscribe watch from MongoDB and it doesn't work. this is my Subscribe Code:

```
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.
            fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider
                    .builder()
                    .automatic(true)
                    .build()));
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
    MongoCollection<Product> collection = db.getCollection("product", Product.class);
    collection.watch(Product.class)
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ChangeStreamDocument<Product>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                    System.out.println("onSubscribe");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ChangeStreamDocument<Product> documentChangeStreamDocument) {
                    System.out.println("onNext");

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.out.println("onError");

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    System.out.println("onComplete");

                }
            });
```

I can see only on console this text 'onSubscribe' but it doesn't work with function onNext. I don't know what I doing wrong.

Thank you for advice for help.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: @Joe I think every time when I add something to specific collection, metod name onNext should be invoke. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.
what's your mongoDB version 
I updated my MongoDB version to V4.2 add Replica Set, then it works

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("serverIp", port);
 MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName");
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collectionName");
 List<Bson> pipeline = singletonList(Aggregates.match(
       Filters.in("operationType", asList("insert", "update", "delete"))));
 MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> watchCursor = 
 collection.watch().iterator();
 LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(watchCursor));
 LOGGER.info("== open cursor ==");

 Runnable task = () -> {
     LOGGER.info("\tWaiting for events");
     while (watchCursor.hasNext()) {
         LOGGER.info("Yes!!!");
         LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(watchCursor.next()));
     }
 };
 new Thread(task).start();
```